Signing transaction payload with private key
The question is how to sign a transaction payload with a private key and send it to the chain. We are compiling an extrinsic:
const keyring = new Keyring({ type: "ed25519" });
const secretKey = Uint8Array.from([...]);
const pair = keyring.addFromSeed(secretKey);
const blockHash = api.rpc.chain.getBlock().block.header.hash.toHex();

const tx = api.tx.balances.transfer(AN_ADDR, 12345);

const payload = api.createType('ExtrinsicPayload', {
  method: tx.toHex(),
  era: 0
  nonce: (await api.rpc.system.accountNextIndex(pair.address)).toHex()
  tip: 0 
  specVersion: api.runtimeVersion.specVersion,
  genesisHash: api.genesisHash,
  blockHash:  blockHash,
}, { version: 4 });

Next, we sign and send:
const signature = pair.sign(payload.toU8a(true), { withType: true });
const sigHex = u8aToHex(signature);
const address = pair.address;
tx.addSignature(address, sigHex, payload.toU8a(true));
const hash = await tx.send();

But we get the error “1010: invalid transaction: transaction has a bad signature” when sending it to the chain.
If we sign it like this, then everything works, but this option does not suit us:
await tx.signAsync(pair, {
          blockHash: blockHash,
          nonce: nonce,
          era: 0
});
const hash = await tx.send();

Apparently we are forming the payload incorrectly, but we don’t understand what needs to be corrected in it for everything to work.
